# Displaying a two dimensional array

Tags: c

I am trying to display a 2-dimensional array.

```
int arr[numRows][numCols] = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,10,11,12,13},{14,15,16,17,18,19,20}};

void display(int p[][numCols])
{
       //printf("\n");
       for (int i = 0; i< numRows;i++)
       {
          for ( int j = 0;i< numCols;j++)
          {
            printf("%i\t",p[i][j]);
          }
          printf("\n");
       }
}
```

But i have some error msg showing up.Not sure how to solve this.

[image]

Screen output: [image]

The whole code is available here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9419/programming-of-3-x-7-trick

Comment: And how are you calling it...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have simple misprint - instead:

```
for ( int j = 0;i< numCols;j++)
```

use

```
for ( int j = 0;j< numCols;j++)
```